# React select - choose value from drop down as per what user enters via keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a requirement that in a select dropdown, user can type any value from key board and if any dropdown options 'starts with' that value, it should be set.

Is it possible via react-select? 
TIA

Comment: What if more than one values start with the same value? Are you talking about dropdown suggestions?

Comment: The first one of all those values should be 'selected' and set.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `react-select` with the prop `onInputChange`.

The prop `onInputChange` works this way:

```
function (
  string,
  {
    action required One of <
    "set-value",
    "input-change",
    "input-blur",
    "menu-close"
    >
  }
) => undefined
```

In your case you want to target the action `input-change` and compare the constant `string` with your options. There you can do the comparison you want, start with or end with or any thing else.

Once you have choosen the option that should get selected you can set your new `value` prop.